# Android parent activity not on back stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have parent activity and when I click on button then start child activity `startActivityForResult` .

So the problem is that parent action is not on stack anymore when I start child activity, and when child activity returns result, there is no parent activity to return to so I get `NullPointerException`.

I'm checking stack with this cmd

```
adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i run
```

When I run some other activity (from other sdk I'm using) there are two activities from my app on stack.

**How can I achieve that state so my custom child activity returns to parent and parent activity does not get poped from stack when I call child activity?**

**Maybe some flags on running activity? Any ideas?**

EDIT:

Starting main activity ( from login activity)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
appContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Starting child activity (just regular activity in this case for testing):

```
 Button scan = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dummy_layout);
        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.getContext(),DummyActivity.class);
                startActivity(cameraIntent);
            }
        });
```

Activities in manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.DummyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
             />
```

UPDATE:

In one moment when debugging when I press back on DummyActivity there are both of them on stack, and app returns to MainActivity but objects I've used before in MainActivity are missing so I get null pointer.

And it seems like when I start my child activity all bottom sheets I'm using are being dismissed automatically by system.

And yeah, I got tons of `'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.app.activity.MainActivity.access$super` errors. could that be te thing?

Comment: put your code here

Comment: how do you launch your child activity?

Comment: please verify that you are not calling **finish()** at the time of **startActivityForResult**?

Comment: @VishalPatoliya here is the code

Comment: @RahulSharma I've checked, i don't call finish in MainActivity

When I start new activity onPause is called on MainActivity

Comment: @T0plomj3r Where is `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: @TOP I've changed it in this example so I could test behaviour. But I'm using startActivityForResult in code. I'm just trying to figure out why It's not on backstack.

Comment: @T0plomj3rCould you please put your Manifest here?

Comment: @TOP here it is

Comment: @T0plomj3r are you doing anything inside **onPause** of **MainActivity**?

Comment: @RahulSharma no, I haven't tried that, but I had to try to modify onDismiss methods that are invoked when child activity launches. Althougt I can store objects that cause NullPointer and reuse them when Activity starts again, the problem is that I use BottomSheetDialogs and Button for starting new activity is nested in two BottomSheetDialogs. 

But I don't know how to open dialogs after activity is restored. It will cause only activity not to crash, not to restore full state as it was :/

Comment: @T0plomj3r when your activity restart its **onResume** method will run. You can open your dialog in this method.

Comment: @RahulSharma I'll try that approach if everything other fails. It feels kinda hack solution so I'd rather avoid that.  There is one other thing, I get lots of

'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.app.activity.MainActivity.access$super errors. Could that be the thing? Cause this code used to work utill 3 days ago, nothing changed in code, so I assume some dependancy update might cause the issue.

Comment: ok. is it necessary to dismiss the dialog before moving to another activity for you?

Comment: As you said that you have to reopen it when you come back yo prev activity?

Comment: @RahulSharma dialogs should not dismiss. They should stay in same state after activity finishes. But they dismiss althought I don't want them to when I start new activity

Comment: ok. Then one more suggestion from my side is just start your activity using **startActivityFromResult** and when you finish your second activity use **setResult** and in prev activity handle **onActivityResult** method and open your dialog here.

Comment: Have you enabled the developer option "Don't keep activities"?

Comment: @DavidWasser no i haven't. Seems like issue occurs only on my low end android device (Galaxy s3 4.4) but not on newer devices.

Comment: Do you have memory issues? How many extras of what type are you adding to your `Intent`s?

Comment: I wouldn't call Samsung Galaxy S3 a "low-end" device :-)